# Austria: partial expenses refund for training / education courses

Tags: austria

I've heard that in Austria (Tirol) the government provides a 30% refund for training / education courses useful for work. Is it true? Where can I find more details?

Comment: Formative/Formation do you mean formal?

Comment: @Karlson: something like a language course or development course or something like that. I've edited the question.

Comment: For starters, “Bei Selbstständigkeit” means “In case of self-employment”. Are you self-employed?

Comment: @GaëlLaurans: thanks for the translation! No, I'm not. Now I will edit the question for acknowledge people who expatriates in austria of this refund possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's correct. Here it's possible to read the additional information: [link](https://www.tirol.gv.at/arbeit-wirtschaft/arbeit/arbeitsmarktfoerderung/bildungsgeld-update/)

It's also possible to fill the module [online](https://portal.tirol.gv.at/XGovForms/XFormsServlet?form=/forms/sgamf_bildungsgeld.xhtml#currentAnker) but it's strictly mandatory to fill in the form in 15 days from the beginning of the course. So read the information carefully. According to other collegues' experiences, the refund should arrive in a short time (1 month?) after the end of the course.

In Austria, also, some kinds of expenses for work (i.e. training course) are also deductible from the taxes at the end of the year. So I think, but I'm not sure, that it's possible to deduct from taxes the remaining expenses.

To make an example the cost of my German course was 280€. I will get 30% refund in some months, about 85€. At the end of the year I will write in my tax document that I've payed 195€ for a training course and ask the government if I can get back other money.

My impression is that the burocracy here works. You can also fill a lot of forms online (not as many as in England, but not so bad as in Italy).